# what should I put in the field of 'referrers' while getting the browser key. Android app development

Tags: android

I am making an android app to display places near current location in map. I know I need to use Google Places. Do i need to get browser api key? if yes, then what should I put in  the field of 'referrers' while getting the browser key. Note: I do not have any website.
Please reply. Thanks in advance

Comment: Actually the code does need browser key. Cant go further without browser key

Comment: In the google console you can choose "Android App" when you generate a client id/key

Comment: For your case you have to use Android key(different for debug & release)